# InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

i'm intend to fetch user's data after login in .net core mvc, but it comes this error, what it is? and how to fix it?

InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser, Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, give the 'userManager' parameter a non-null default value.

```
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public void HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> MySchedule(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        var CourseChosen = from m in _context.CourseChosen
                               select m;
        var userid = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
        if (userid == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            var identification = user.StudentId;
            CourseChosen = CourseChosen.Where(x => x.StudentId == identification);

            var coursechosen = new MyCourse
            {
                MyCourses = await CourseChosen.ToListAsync()
            };

            return View(coursechosen);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Weber Wang, this error caused by `UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager` as parameter in `MySchedule` action. Just remove it.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I removed it, but it shows 
"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
" 
at 
var userid = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
what does it mean?

Comment: Hi @Weber Wang, Please first check if `HttpContext.User` contains data before using `_userManager.GetUserId`.

Comment: @Rena, it shows that _userManager is null, so I think I didn't get data at
    public void HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
i have no idea what happened

Comment: Hi @Weber Wang, `public void HomeController` is not correct as a constructor. `void` is no need.

Comment: Hi @Weber Wang, I have updated my answer about how to DI UserManager.

Comment: @Rena but if I delete 'void', it will show the error 'Method must have a return type'

Comment: Hi @Weber Wang, Please, Constructor is no need a return type. I think you need share where did you put it.You create a wrong constructor. Check my answer below. If you put them in HomeController class, the constructor should be `public HomeController()`. The constructor name should be the same with the class name.

Comment: @Rena Thank u very very much, it works! i have been stucked into this for so long!

Comment: Glad it could help you.

Comment: @Rena, Hello Rena, may I ask you to help me out with this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69131777/how-to-open-index-first-not-identity-when-starting-up-the-web-app-donet-core-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,
> Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=5.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]'. Model bound
> complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a
> parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary
> constructor. Alternatively, give the 'userManager' parameter a
> non-null default value.

This error caused by using `UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager` as parameter in `MySchedule` action.

Just change:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MySchedule(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
```

To:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MySchedule()
```

For how to DI UserManager, it shold be:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    //Constructor name should be the same as the class
    public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    //action below..
    //request url should be: Home/MySchedule if you use MVC

    public async Task<IActionResult> MySchedule()
    {....}
}
```