# How to open Index first not identity when starting up the web app? ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use Identity as my authentication, but it shows login page first, not index when I start up apps. I want login page appear after pushing login button in navigation bar of index.

I just wondering beside `startup.cs`, where can I make the adjustment?

[image: This is my startup.cs code]

[image: This is login page]

Comment: Mark the action you want to show up with `[AllowAnonymous]`

Comment: @abdusco excuse me i don't get it, you mean to place [AllowAnonymous] to somewhere? If yes, where should i place it?

Comment: on the action method for the index/home page

Answer (score 0):

Ans: To place [AllowAnonymous] on the top of Index action like this
[This is answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XwDN.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).